# Deleting a notebook cell using only the keyboard

Tags: front-end, notebooks, keyboard

I am working on a laptop (thus I don't have the numeric pad). To erase a cell in Mathematica I always have to look on the right of the notebook window to find the bracket associated to the line, and then push del on my keyboard.

This is really inefficient because I always have to be carefull to erase the proper cell.

Isn't there a way to directly erase a cell by selecting its text and pushing a given key (selecting text + del will delete the text but not the cell).

Also, my keyboard is AZERTY (French keyboard).

Comment: This one of those questions I'm sure *lots* want to ask..but are too embarrassed and just frustratingly use the mouse for cell modification....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the cursor between cells, then press and hold SHIFT and select whole cells up or downwards with your arrow keys. If you press DELETE then this will delete the selected cells.

Comment: Allright. The trick is to put the cursor between the cell (and not on the text of a cell to do so). Thanks !